# Accessing data in a JavaScript arrray

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find object by id in array of javascript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects)

So I have this:

```
mapArray=
[{"Title":"crop_rotation","subs":"5,6,7,10"},
{"Title":"cover_crops","subs":"2,5,7,8,9,13,14"},
{"Title":"binary_wetlands","subs":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11"}]
```

I am trying to access the subs value based on the Title. I am trying

```
listofSubs=mapArray["crop_rotation"]("subs");
```

I don't get anything returned. What am I missing here? I need to take that list and convert to a string but I assume it will come out as a string since I have the object already parsed? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to find the object with the specific title. You have to do this by iterating over the array and comparing each object's `Title` against your value:

```
function find(arr, key, value) {
    for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(arr[i][key] === value)) {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }
    // return {}; // if you would want it null-safe
}
```

Then you can access the corresponding `subs` property:

```
var obj = find(mapArray, 'Title', 'crop_rotation');
if(obj) {
    var listofSubs = obj.subs;
}
```

---

An explanation for why your code does not work:

```
mapArray["crop_rotation"]("subs");
//      |-      1      -|-   2  -|
```

- `|1|` tries to access the property `crop_rotation` of the object in `mapArray`. Arrays don't have such properties and in your case no object does. `crop_rotation` is the **value** of one of the properties.
- `|2|` is a function call. It tries to call the function referenced by `mapArray["crop_rotation"]` and passes `"subs"` as first argument. It throws an error if `mapArray["crop_rotation"]` is not a function (like in your case).

---

**Further information:**

- [MDN JavaScript Guide # Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object)
- [MDN JavaScript Guide # Working with Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
- [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-access-a-specific-value)

Comment: Excellent answer and a piece of code I will put in the arsenal. Thanks for your help Felix.

Comment: $.each(forMapArray, function(index, value) { 
 if (forMapArray[index]["Title"]=="crop_rotation"){
 alert("YES");
 doCropRotation(); 
     }
});

Comment: @jeynon: Yep, for processing each object that fullfils a certain criteria, this makes sense. Note that you can also just do: `if(value["Title"]=="crop_rotation"){...}`

Answer (score 0):

`alert(mapArray[0].Title)` = "crop_rotation"

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an array of objects there. And arrays are numerically indexed. So to get the value you are looking for:

```
mapArray;    // returns array of objects
mapArray[0]; // returns first object in the array

// returns the value of the `"subs"` key in the first object in the array
mapArray[0]['subs'];
```

Note this wont find it by title, you need a bit more logic for that. See Felix Kling's answer to do that,

Answer (score 0):

You can' just access list(array) by field of it's element. It's named list(array) for purpose - it's not indexed by anything but position. So you can access list like this mapArray[0]. If want to access it by title You should have structur like this

```
{ "crop_rotation": ...,
  "cover_crops" :....,
  .... 
}
```

If your input is fixed that you can't change it you have to pre-process it to fit your needs. So you have to iterate over the array and make dictionary out of it changing `"Title"` values into keys of your new dictionary.